# Extract Data From SVG

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have the following code saved to a local html file

```
<object id="PriceAdvisorFrame" type="image/svg+xml" data="https://www.kbb.com/Api/3.9.448.0/71071/vehicle/upa/PriceAdvisor/meter.svg?action=Get&amp;intent=buy-used&amp;pricetype=Private Party&amp;zipcode=99517&amp;vehicleid=439604&amp;hideMonthlyPayment=True&amp;condition=verygood&amp;mileage=11795" style="width: 100%;"></object>
```

I am trying to extract the cost from the html when the it is executed a chrome browser. Html code I am trying to parse out is shown below. However this code does not appear when the file is requested using selenium.

```
<text xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14" font-weight="700" fill="#333333" y="-8">$27,938</text>
<text xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14" font-weight="400" fill="#333333" y="-26">Private Party Value</text>
<text xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" text-anchor="middle" font-size="20" font-weight="700" fill="#ffffff" y="-48">$26,995 - $28,888</text>
<text xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14" font-weight="400" fill="#ffffff" y="-68.8">Private Party Range</text>
```

Here is my code thus far:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.50 Safari/537.36'    
options.add_argument('user-agent={0}'.format(user_agent))
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.get('file:///F:/Onedrive/Python/KBB/test.html')
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('text').text)
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: can't you get data directly from url `https://www.kbb.com/...` ? Maybe you will no need `Selenium` but `requests` and it will work faster. But remember to use `&` instead of `&amp;`

Answer (score 1):

The `'text'` you mean is not `css_selector`, it is `tag_name`. You can use `.find_elements_*` to collect all elements and then to extract the text them.

```
driver.get('file:///F:/Onedrive/Python/KBB/test.html')

elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('text')
for element in elements:
    text = element.text
    if "$" in text:
        print(text)
```

Comment: I don't know if you created an html file and tested the code yourself but the problem is that the text tags only appear when I inspect the html code from my browser. The HTML code that the selenium driver sees is only the HTML code that I posted in the first block of code. How do I get the driver to execute the html object to allow it to see the data located in the svg?

Answer (score 1):

The html when loaded into browser doesn't have your desired info in the `driver.page_source` so you cannot select in this way. The browser itself makes a GET request, based on the `data` attribute, and renders the new content - the file, however, is not updated. You could `.get` to the `data` source or use `requests`.

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'path\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.html')
print(driver.page_source)
driver.get(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[data]').get_attribute('data'))
elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR , 'text')))
if elem is not None:
    print(elem.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

To access SVG element you need to use following xpath.

> //*[name()='text']

or

> //*[local-name()='text']

Try the below code.

```
elements=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//*[name()='text']")))
for ele in elements:
  print(ele.text)
```

To Execute above code you need to import followings.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```